# Position of UITableView of UITalbeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

How can i customize the Vertical postion of `UITableView` of `UITableViewController`.I am trying to show the table(3 cells) at the middle of the window . My class is inheriting `UITableViewController` class. Please someone give me suggestions. or Alternative ways to do this.
Thank You.

Comment: You can’t. UITableViewController is useless, it's just a UIViewController with a delegate/dataSource automatically set for its table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create an UIViewController, and put an UITableView in it. I think you can set the origin.y of the tableView. Make sure to set the UITableView's datasource and delegate. Good luck.

Comment: Is it posible to do origin.y change in `UITableViewController` table view??

Comment: @EmonEmoni I don't think so:)